# Tic Tac Toe: X go first

Tags: javascript

I took this code from the internet and want to modify it so that regardless of which symbol I select, the x starts first (the computer in this case).

- If I select to play with X, I will start first and the computer will play with O.
- If I select to play with O, the computer will receive X and make the first move.

```
const selectBox = document.querySelector(".select-box"),
      selectBtnX = selectBox.querySelector(".options .playerX"),
      selectBtnO = selectBox.querySelector(".options .playerO"),
      playBoard = document.querySelector(".play-board"),
      players = document.querySelector(".players"),
      allBox = document.querySelectorAll("section span"),
      resultBox = document.querySelector(".result-box"),
      wonText = resultBox.querySelector(".won-text"),
      replayBtn = resultBox.querySelector("button");

let x = 'x';
let O = 'O';

window.onload = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < allBox.length; i++) {
        allBox[i].setAttribute("onclick", "clickedBox(this)");
    }
}
selectBtnX.onclick = () => {
    selectBox.classList.add("hide");
    playBoard.classList.add("show");
}
selectBtnO.onclick = () => {
    selectBox.classList.add("hide");
    playBoard.classList.add("show");
    players.setAttribute("class", "players active player");
}

let playerXIcon = "fas fa-times",
    playerOIcon = "far fa-circle",
    playerSign = "X",
    runBot = true;
    
function clickedBox(element) {
    if (players.classList.contains("player")) {
        playerSign = "O";
        element.innerHTML = `<i class="${playerOIcon}"></i>`;
        players.classList.remove("active");
        element.setAttribute("id", playerSign);
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = `<i class="${playerXIcon}"></i>`;
        element.setAttribute("id", playerSign);
        players.classList.add("active");
    }
    selectWinner();
    element.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    playBoard.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    let randomTimeDelay = ((Math.random() * 1000) + 200).toFixed();
    setTimeout(() => {
        bot(runBot);
    }, randomTimeDelay);
}

function bot() {
    let array = [];
    if (runBot) {
        playerSign = "O";
        for (let i = 0; i < allBox.length; i++) {
            if (allBox[i].childElementCount == 0) {
                array.push(i);
            }
        }
        let randomBox = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
        if (array.length > 0) {
            if (players.classList.contains("player")) {
                playerSign = "X";
                allBox[randomBox].innerHTML = `<i class="${playerXIcon}"></i>`;
                allBox[randomBox].setAttribute("id", playerSign);
                players.classList.add("active");
            } else {
                allBox[randomBox].innerHTML = `<i class="${playerOIcon}"></i>`;
                players.classList.remove("active");
                allBox[randomBox].setAttribute("id", playerSign);
            }
            selectWinner();
        }
        allBox[randomBox].style.pointerEvents = "none";
        playBoard.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        playerSign = "X";
    }
}

function getIdVal(classname) {
    return document.querySelector(".box" + classname).id;
}

function checkIdSign(val1, val2, val3, sign) {
    if (getIdVal(val1) == sign && getIdVal(val2) == sign && getIdVal(val3) == sign) {
        return true;
    }
}

function selectWinner() {
    if (checkIdSign(1, 2, 3, playerSign) || checkIdSign(4, 5, 6, playerSign) || checkIdSign(7, 8, 9, playerSign) || checkIdSign(1, 4, 7, playerSign) || checkIdSign(2, 5, 8, playerSign) || checkIdSign(3, 6, 9, playerSign) || checkIdSign(1, 5, 9, playerSign) || checkIdSign(3, 5, 7, playerSign)) {
        runBot = false;
        bot(runBot);
        setTimeout(() => {
            resultBox.classList.add("show");
            playBoard.classList.remove("show");
        }, 700);
        wonText.innerHTML = `<p>${playerSign}</p> wins!`;
    } else {
        if (getIdVal(1) != "" && getIdVal(2) != "" && getIdVal(3) != "" && getIdVal(4) != "" && getIdVal(5) != "" && getIdVal(6) != "" && getIdVal(7) != "" && getIdVal(8) != "" && getIdVal(9) != "") {
            runBot = false;
            bot(runBot);
            setTimeout(() => {
                resultBox.classList.add("show");
                playBoard.classList.remove("show");
            }, 700);
            wonText.textContent = "It's a draw!";
        }
    }
}

replayBtn.onclick = () => {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Can you share HTML?

Comment: yes bro https://codepen.io/sebastian-mihai-ciuc/pen/QWrRJVx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you select to play with 0, you should call `bot` to make a first move.

You can refer

```
selectBtnO.onclick = () => {
    selectBox.classList.add("hide");
    playBoard.classList.add("show");
    players.setAttribute("class", "players active player");
    bot(true); // call bot when you selet to play with O
}
```